# ScrollToPosition always scrolls to the last row in my section

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, scroll

I have a tableview with sections. Each sections is a month. So I've section for June, July,August,...

What I want to do now is when the tableview shows up, it immediately scrolls down to the month of today. I have the following function for that.

```
-(void)scrollToPosition{
  NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
    NSString *strDate = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@",now];
    NSArray *arr = [strDate componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
    NSString *str;
    str = [arr objectAtIndex:0];
    NSLog(@"strdate: %@",str); // strdate: 2011-02-28

    NSArray *arr_my = [str componentsSeparatedByString:@"-"];

    NSInteger month = [[arr_my objectAtIndex:1] intValue];
    NSLog(@"month - 5 %d",month -5);

    NSIndexPath *path = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:month -5];
    NSLog(@"path = %@",path);
    [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:path atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle animated:YES];

}
```

The reason that I do **month-5** is that my tableview start at the month June. What my problem is, is that it scrolls down to the last row of the section instead of the first. Can anybody help me?

Kind regards,

**EDIT**

```
My tableview looks likes this. 

---Section 1: June -----
    - row 1 (12-06-2012)
    - row 2 (14-06-2012)
    - row 3 (20-06-2012)
    - row 4 (22-06-2012)
---Section 2: July -----
    - row 1 (2-07-2012)
    - row 2 (14-07-2012)
    - row 3 (21-07-2012)
    - row 4 (27-07-2012)
---Section 3: August -----
    - row 1 (2-08-2012)
    - row 2 (14-08-2012)
---Section 4: September -----
    - row 1 (17-09-2012)
---Section 5: Oktober -----
    - row 1
    - row 2
    - row 3
    - row 4
---Section 6: November -----
    - row 1
    - row 2
    - row 3
    - row 4
---Section 7: December -----
    - row 1
    - row 2
    - row 3
---Section 8: January -----
    - row 1
    - row 2
```

**EDIT: screenshot**

Here you can see a screenshot of how my tableview looks after scrolling. [Screenshot](http://www.flickr.com/photos/74322780@N08/8147273451/in/photostream)

Comment: If the return value of month is 2 then it will scroll to section -3 row 1. I hope you are creating the correct indexpath here. Can you give more details on which row you want it to scroll in which section.

Comment: @PraveenS Yes I know that there is some problem with the month. I need to solve it with an if function. but the section is at the moment Ok, I've a problem with the row.

Comment: @PraveenS I've edited my question with how my tableview looks like

Comment: How do you see that it scrolls to the bottom of the section, is the last row in the middle of the table after scrolling ?

Comment: @A-Live No, after scrolling it is the first row in my tableview.

Comment: @A-Live I've added a screenshot with how the tableview looks after scrolling.

Comment: Are you sure the section is calculated correctly then ? With your code you are scrolling to the second row of some section and you want to see it in the middle of the table, I believe that is what happens (as expected as that is what is written in the code) and the problems are that the section index is not correct and you expect the target row to be at the top while you specified it to be in the middle. Thanks for the screenshot, what is the `path` value for this case ?

Comment: @A-Live please hold on for a moment, Xcode is reinstalling :)

Comment: @A-Live it gives the following indexPath path = <NSIndexPath 0x1edf8b10> 2 indexes [6, 1]

Comment: So that's the index path of the second row of the December section (following your datasource listing) and you are using UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle - the cell is displayed in the middle of the table. If you want to see the November section's first row at the top of the table, the section index must be `-1` and you are gong to use  `UITableViewScrollPositionTop`. Does it make sense for you ?

Comment: Yes, the problem was UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle. Beginner mistake, but still thank you for your help! If you answer it as an answer I will mark it as correct.

Comment: Oops, i missed the position too. ATB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, that the section index starts at **0** not at **1**.

So when your returned month is **6** your calling:

```
NSIndexPath *path = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:1]; // month - 5 = 1
[self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:path atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle animated:YES];
```

But you should call:

```
NSIndexPath *path = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:0];
```

So your scrolling to the section that is 1 **below** the section you actually wanted to scroll to. That's why it appears as if it would scroll to the last row of the previous section.

Replace `month - 5` by `month - 6` and it should work as you want.

By the way I would suggest to modify your code to retrieve the current month like this:

```
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM"];
int month = [[dateFormatter stringFromDate:now] intValue];
//...
```